# Validating a HUGE XML file

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I'm trying to find a way to validate a large XML file against an XSD. I saw the question [...best way to validate an XML...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-xml-file-against-an-xsd-file) but the answers all pointed to using the Xerces library for validation. The only problem is, when I use that library to validate a 180 MB file then I get an OutOfMemoryException.

Are there any other tools,libraries, strategies for validating a larger than normal XML file?

EDIT: The SAX solution worked for java validation, but the other two suggestions for the libxml tool were very helpful as well for validation  outside of java.

Comment: For an easy to use Windows tool you can use [XML ValidatorBuddy](http://www.xml-tools.com/ValidatorBuddy.htm) which uses the Xerces SAX parser internally to validate huge files.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Instead of using a DOMParser, use a SAXParser.  This reads from an input stream or reader so you can keep the XML on disk instead of loading it all into memory.

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(true);
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
reader.setErrorHandler(new SimpleErrorHandler());
reader.parse(new InputSource(new FileReader ("document.xml")));
```

Comment: you have not provided an XSD to validate here. How that can be done?

Answer (score 8):

Use [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/), which performs validation *and* has a streaming mode.

Comment: @oob Yes, libxml2 works perfectly. Also, if anyone is looking for the Windows binaries, they are here: ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/

Answer (score 3):

Personally I like to use [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) which has a command line interface, and works on streams. It is a set of tools built on Libxml2.

Answer (score 1):

SAX and libXML will help, as already mentioned. You could also try increasing the maximum heap size for the JVM using the -Xmx option. E.g. to set the maximum heap size to 512MB: `java -Xmx512m com.foo.MyClass`