# Quick Way to Validate XML/Identify Point of Brokenness

Tags: xml

How does one check the validity of an XML file to show where the xml error occurs?

Firefox can do it, but I'd like to do it in linux/windows command line.

eg.  I've got a large-ish (90MB) XML file from Excel, saved in XML Spreadsheet 2003 format. It contains various invalid data, so that Firefox spits out messages like this:

```
Line Number 790402, Column 65:
<Cell ss:StyleID="s18"><Data ss:Type="String">Here's some data I&#5;?Bnternational</Data></Cell>
```

Firefox is quite slow at parsing my XML(presumably because it's keeping it all in memory ready to render into a nice navigable tree). I'm not bothered about validation against an XSD, just want to know if the XML is well-formed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML Schema (XSD) validation tool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124865/xml-schema-xsd-validation-tool)

Comment: No it's not - this question explicitly mentions that it's not about validating against an XSD, whereas that question is entirely about validating an XSD.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There's a linux command called [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) that is good for this. It's very fast, handles honking great files without barfing, and gives useful validation error messages.

Comment: Cool stuff. Even validation supported... How could I ever live without it? +1

Comment: `xmllint --valid filename.xml` to validate the document in addition to std well-formed check 
`xmllint --schema name.xsd filename.xml` to validate against a schema file

Comment: install: `sudo apt install libxml2-utils`

Comment: I found that without the --noout switch it'll dump out the xml as well, if you want xmllint to show you just where it's failing; xmllint --valid --noout filename.xml

Answer (score 19):

The other answer one-liner-fied:

```
python -c "import sys, xml.dom.minidom as d; d.parse(sys.argv[1])" FILE
```

Comment: what's the use of -c flag here?

Comment: `python -h`  →  `-c cmd : program passed in as string (terminates option list)`

Answer (score 3):

You could use features of other languages for that. E.g., a two-liner in Python:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as dom
dom.parse ('test.xml')
```

This will show the problem, and is quite performant. I remember there was an XML toolkit that worked quite well from within bash, but I can't find a link to that right now.

Cheers,

**Edit:** [This question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663/validating-a-huge-xml-file) suggested using SAX over dom, since it'd be more performant. A ready-to-use Python script would then look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import xml.sax as sax
parser = sax.make_parser ()
parser.parse (open ('test.xml'))
```

**Edit 2:** I remember again, the tool was [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/). I found it to be quite nice, when I used it two years ago.

Comment: Me too, but for really large XML files you'll be happy for every bit of performance you can squeeze from the tool.

Answer (score 2):

I always recommend the [XML Starlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) command line utilities.

They provide validation, querying, formatting, editing of documents straight from the command line, and they're invaluable for this sort of work, or sanity-checking documents, chopping sections out via XPath etc.

Comment: Haha! You're too late. I remembered it just on time. ;-)

Comment: It obviously made a big impression on you

Comment: Yes, three years ago, when I started with XML, it was a hassle to work with it on the command line. Then I found XML Starlet and suddenly it got really cool working with XML in my bash scripts.

Answer (score 1):

There's yet another new-ish (from 2013) commandline tool that is based on the Xerces parser for doing XML Schema validation.  It's called xjparse (https://xjparse.org).  So far, I've found this tool to be slow-ish, but one of the more complete schema validators, especially if you happen to have xsd's that include/import other xsd's.  It also seems to be available on most of the popular Linux distros.

**Edit**: This topic/issue recently resurfaced for me *again*.   This time I wrote a fairly simple Ruby script utilizing the Nokogiri gem.  The main trick was to first parse the XML for it's XSD namespace documents, then create a "schema" document with them so that could then be used to validate the original XML.

**Edit 2**: made the script into a gem available on rubygems.org

`gem install validate_xml_xsi`