# Fastest way check xml well formed, and pinpoint problems for Windows Developer

Tags: xml, debugging, validation

Just wondering if somebody could suggest the quickest tool for the situations where you know somebody committed some invalid XML and you want to find it really fast.

Right now I've been using [XML Copy Editor](http://xml-copy-editor.sourceforge.net/).

Any other suggestions?  I will eventually put validation commit hooks to prevent people from committing invalid .xml files.

Thanks

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142438/quick-way-to-validate-xml-identify-point-of-brokenness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I use xmllint and I'm happy with it. Thought it is a command line tool.

Comment: xmllint is a linux tool, though there's apparently a windows port (http://code.google.com/p/xmllint/).

Answer (score 0):

Open it using Internet Explorer.
If it finds any non-compliance will point the first failure.

Comment: That's a slow way of doing it. Ever tried loading a huge XML file in IE? It spends *forever* rendering the XML into a nice navigable, clickable DOM (or at least, that's what I assume it's spending time doing).

Comment: I agree, does not apply to large files, but meets most of the cases.