# xsd validation, get the object that is invalid

Tags: python, xml, xsd-validation

I have a large XML file (3 MB+) and i have an XSD to validate it against.

I am using python and LXML. I started from this script <>. Which does the validation fine, including giving me the line number. But the problem the file is on one line, so when i validate all i get is the error showing on line 1. when i use pretty print to split the lines up for me it maxes out at line 65535.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pretty-print your XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1206856/1497596) to add newlines to it. Then put it through your validator to get a more helpful line number.

**EDIT:** On re-reading your question, I see that you have used Notepad++ to add the newlines. But that **LXML** apparently has a size limitation when it comings to validating your XML.

For a general approach to this problem, please see [Validating a HUGE XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40663/1497596). In particular, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40678/1497596) begins with:

> Instead of using a **DOMParser**, use a **SAXParser**. This reads from an
>   input stream or reader so you can keep the XML on disk instead of
>   loading it all into memory.

Basically, you need to use a **streaming approach** which SAX offers. So, if your requirement is that you must validate your file in Python, then you'll need to find validation approach based on streaming. (Perhap **LXML** offers validation in a streaming fashion?)

However, if your validation requirements are more flexible, then consider a specialized tool such as [XMLStarlet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40956/1497596).

For example, here's how to validate an XML file against an XSD from the [XMLStarlet entry on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLStarlet):

```
xmlstarlet val -e -s my.xsd my.xml
```

And testimonial on using [XMLStarlet on very large files](https://niftybits.wordpress.com/2008/03/27/working-with-huge-xml-files-tools-of-the-trade/).

Comment: While this does make a valid workaround, i would still prefer the object but i can work with this, thanks!