# StAX XML formatting in Java

Tags: java, xml, formatting, stax, woodstox

Is it possible using StAX (specifically woodstox) to format the output xml with newlines and tabs, i.e. in the form:

```
<element1>
  <element2>
   someData
  </element2>
</element1>
```

instead of:

```
<element1><element2>someData</element2></element1>
```

If this is not possible in woodstox, is there any other lightweight libs that can do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Via the JDK: `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");`.

Comment: The link to the approach misses a colon after the https

Comment: @Josh The link is broken. This approach is proposed on SO : [Formatting XML file using StAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949203/formatting-xml-file-using-stax/2952945#2952945)

Comment: I added a bit more context in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38371920/480894

Comment: That is not answer. What transformer? How to use it?

Comment: @pavel_k https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html I would assume that if you are programming in Java you know how to reference Java documentation and have attempted to first implement the solution yourself

Comment: see also the OutputKeys class in the same package https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html

Answer (score 25):

There is com.sun.xml.txw2.output.IndentingXMLStreamWriter

```
XMLOutputFactory xmlof = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamWriter writer = new IndentingXMLStreamWriter(xmlof.createXMLStreamWriter(out));
```

Comment: as far as I can see the namespace either has an error in it or has moved to com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.output.

Comment: @epeleg No, the "internal" version is bundled with the JRE. You can get the non-internal version by explicitly adding JAXB-RI as a dependency.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using the StAX cursor API, you can indent the output by wrapping the XMLStreamWriter in an [indenting proxy](http://ewernli.wordpress.com/2009/06/18/stax-pretty-printer/). I tried this in my own project and it worked nicely.

Answer (score 8):

Using the JDK [Transformer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html):

```
public String transform(String xml) throws XMLStreamException, TransformerException
{
    Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    t.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
    Writer out = new StringWriter();
    t.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)), new StreamResult(out));
    return out.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about [StaxMate](https://github.com/FasterXML/StaxMate):

http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2006/09/entry_21.html

Works well with Woodstox, fast, low-memory usage (no in-memory tree built), and indents like so:

---

```
SMOutputFactory sf = new SMOutputFactory(XMLOutputFactory.newInstance());
SMOutputDocument doc = sf.createOutputDocument(new FileOutputStream("output.xml"));
doc.setIndentation("\n ", 1, 2); // for unix linefeed, 2 spaces per level    
// write doc like:    
SMOutputElement root = doc.addElement("element1");    
root.addElement("element2").addCharacters("someData");    
doc.closeRoot(); // important, flushes, closes output
```

---

Answer (score 4):

Rather than relying on a com.sun...class that might go away (or get renamed com.oracle...class), I recommend downloading the [StAX utility classes](http://java.net/projects/stax-utils/pages/Home) from java.net. This package contains a IndentingXMLStreamWriter class that works nicely. (Source and javadoc are included in the download.)

Answer (score 2):

if you are using XMLEventWriter, then an easier way to do that is:

```
XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLEventWriter writer = outputFactory.createXMLEventWriter(w);
        XMLEventFactory eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
        Characters newLine = eventFactory.createCharacters("\n"); 
        writer.add(startRoot);
        writer.add(newLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the iterating method (XMLEventReader), can't you just attach a new line '\n' character to the relevant XMLEvents when writing to your XML file?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about stax, but there was a recent discussion about pretty printing xml here

[pretty print xml from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java)

this was my attempt at a solution

[How to pretty print XML from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java#260314)

using the **org.dom4j.io.OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint()** method

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Batch this requires a subclass since this [JIRA BATCH-1867](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCH-1867)

```
public class IndentingStaxEventItemWriter<T> extends StaxEventItemWriter<T> {

  @Setter
  @Getter
  private boolean indenting = true;

  @Override
  protected XMLEventWriter createXmlEventWriter( XMLOutputFactory outputFactory, Writer writer) throws XMLStreamException {
    if ( isIndenting() ) {
      return new IndentingXMLEventWriter( super.createXmlEventWriter( outputFactory, writer ) );
    }
    else {
      return super.createXmlEventWriter( outputFactory, writer );
    }
  }

}
```

But this requires an additionnal dependency because Spring Batch does not include the code to indent the StAX output:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.java.dev.stax-utils</groupId>
  <artifactId>stax-utils</artifactId>
  <version>20070216</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried this, but when i deploy my application on weblogic and run the job it creates an xml file with &#xd; in each line after the closing tag. How to avoid this?