# How do I prevent a pair of XMLEvent[Reader|Writer] from splitting empty tags into start+end tags?

Tags: java, xml, pretty-print, stax

I have an understanding problem of how the following code works:

```
XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
XMLOutputFactory xof = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();

XMLEventReader reader = xif.createXMLEventReader(/* ... */);
XMLEventWriter writer = xof.createXMLEventWriter(/* ... */);

writer.add(reader);
```

The method writer.add([some reader]) reads all events from reader and writes them consequently. Sadly, following happens:

The input

```
<root><c/></root>
```

gets transformed to

```
<root><c><c/></root>
```

I know, from XML point of view, these are equal trees, but not for a human ;)

What can I do to get the same output?

*FYI: I need a XMLEvent[Reader|Writer] pair later to filter "XML events".*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [list of XMLEvents](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.5/api/javax/xml/stream/events/XMLEvent.html) it seems like there is no way to make the distinction and it will indeed generate a `StartElement` and `EndElement` event. The consumer would need to optimize for the case when a `StartElement` is immediately followed by an `EndElement`.

This is apparently not the case of the `XMLEventReader` returned by the factory. If you want to optimize this behavior yourself, I see no other way than to do something like

- check what's the concrete `XMLEventReader` implementation returned by `createXMLEventReader`
- subclass the `XMLEventReader` implementation to optimize this case
- subclass `XMLInputFactory` and override `createXMLEventReader` to return an instance of your `XMLEventReader` subclass

If this sounds too complicated (or doesn't work), I would suggest that you go with [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290326/stax-xml-formatting-in-java) that uses `XMLStreamWriter`. This one has a dedicated method `writeEmptyElement`.

(Or you can give a try to my [home-made pretty printer](http://www.ewernli.com/web/guest/47), it's based on `XMLStreamWriter`)

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am mistaken, [Woodstox](http://woodstox.codehaus.org) can be configured to either produce empty tags (default), or not (so it'll always output start+end tag, even if there is no content).
Since you can configure this for XMLStreamWriter, and you can then produce XMLEventWriter using that stream writer, it should work as expected.

Comment: _"Unless I am mistaken"_ - who would know better!? ;-)

Comment: :-) -- ok, right, chances are low that I'd be mistaken in this particular matter.