# How to get formatted output when marshalling to XMLEventWriter?

Tags: jaxb, format, marshalling, stax

I am trying to marshal JAXB annotated object into StaX XMLEventWriter, but even when I set marshaller property JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT to true in the result the marshalled object is not formatted.

Thanks

PS: I am using Oracle Java 8 RI and Woodstock Stax

Answer (score 0):

OK I have found the solution.
If I have used XMLStreamWriter, then there is built in wrapper called IndentingXMLStreamWriter, but I could not find same for EventWriter.

Than I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2949222/1462417) with reference to StaX utils.
So I have added to my maven manifest

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.stax-utils</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax-utils</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

and was able to use IndentingXMLEventWriter.