# XML ItemWriter which writes the data in XML format

Tags: java, xml, spring-batch

I have  aspring batch job that use an StaxeventItemWriter , it's works fine . I want the result Xml file to be formatted , how can I do that . is there any property like  ? 
this is my ItemWriter , I put only the relevant part of my code to simplify , if needed I can add the hole job.thanks

```
<bean id="xmlWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
       <property name="resource" value="file:src/main/resources/myFile.xml"></property>
       <property name="rootTagName" value="Users"></property><bean id="MyMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
  <property name="classesToBeBound">
    <list>
       <value>model.myModel</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
       <property name="marshaller" ref="MyMarshaller"></property>

    </bean> 

<bean id="MyMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
      <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
           <value>model.myModel</value>
        </list>
      </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Since you'r writer is StAX based, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290326/stax-xml-formatting-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the `JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT` option on the marshaller with:

```
<bean id="MyMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
  <property name="classesToBeBound">
    <list>
       <value>model.myModel</value>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="marshallerProperties">
    <map>
        <entry>
            <key>
                <util:constant static-field="javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT" />
            </key>
            <value type="java.lang.Boolean">true</value>
        </entry>
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: what is the namespace for (util
  please?

Comment: I added the namespace :xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util". but still not fornmatting the XML file.