# Framework to Verify XSD with XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have an XSD and I want to verify incoming XML files from a webservice against that XSD for schema validation?

Any suggestions or pointers for existing Frameworks in Java to do that? 
Help is appreciated in advance.

Cheers

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-xml-file-against-an-xsd-file

Comment: No, this is a very different problem, since webservices are involved. @Priyank, what web service library are you using?

Comment: Hey guys,
Thanks a lot for inputs. fortunately, I could lay my hands on the piece of code that worked for me. So it's solved for now.. I'll post the solution here in a bit.
-Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in JAXP API (in Java 5 or later). http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-javaxmlvalidapi.html