# How to validate a xml file against a given xsd file while parsing it with a sax parser?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I want to parse a xml file using a SAXParser or XMLReader and verify that the file conforms to a specific xsd **file** (`new File( "example.xsd" )`).

It's easy to

1. do the validation against a xsd file in an extra step using a `Validator` like in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-xml-file-against-an-xsd-file/16054#16054).
2. to validate while parsing by specifying the name of the xsd as `"http://apache.org/xml/properties/schema/external-noNamespaceSchemaLocation"` like in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-xml-file-against-an-xsd-file/15739#15739).

But how can I validate against a `new File( "example.xsd" )` **while parsing**?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming Java 5 or above, set the schema on the [SAXParserFactory](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html#setSchema(javax.xml.validation.Schema)):

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
    .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File("myschema.xsd"));
SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
saxFactory.setSchema(schema);
SAXParser parser = saxFactory.newSAXParser();
parser.parse("data.xml", new DefaultHandler() {
  // TODO: other handler methods
  @Override
  public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
    throw e;
  }
});
```

You handle validation errors by overriding the [error method](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#error(org.xml.sax.SAXParseException)) on your handler and acting as you see fit.

Comment: It seems that the parser still uses the schema defined inside the xml file and not the one I set with `schemaFactory( newSchema(...))`.

Comment: That isn't the behaviour I see (the parser always validates against the schema set on the factory, even if one is set in the document). Without sample documents/code, it is difficult to identify the problem.