# How to handle the different dialects of regular expressions (java vs. xsd)?

Tags: java, regex, xsd

When I try to validate an XML file against an XSD in java ([see this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-xml-file-against-an-xsd-file/16054#16054)) there are some incompatibilities between the regular expressions given in the XSD file and the regular expressions in java.

If there is an regular expression like `"[ab-]"` in the XSD (meaning any of the characters "a", "b" or "-", java complains about a syntax error in the expression.

This is a known bug since 28-MAR-2005, see [Sun bug database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6246667).

**What can I do to work around this bug?** Up to now I try to "correct" the XSD file by replacing the `"[ab-]"` by `"[ab\-]"`, but sometimes this is not an option.

---

**If you have problems with this bug, too, please vote for it at the [Sun bug database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6246667)!**

Comment: To the point: you thus want a *parser* to convert a *regex* pattern? :) I've at least upvoted the particular bug, it looks indeed pretty annoying. Hope they get it fixed sooner.

Comment: A regex converter would be an option. I'm just looking for the best workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Since a bug is already filed, I'd recommend you try a different XML Schema processor.  There's not going to be a lot you can do about it.

If you can preprocess the stream the XSD is coming in on, then you could create a parser which understands the basic regular expression structure and can fix anything that looks of the form [.*-] (where the .star is not a literal in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Although it may not be the best solution in the world, you could consider using the Sax parser.  I have used it for over 3 years now, however I have not done much regex validation with it, so I cannot speak to it's robustness related to that.

Other than that, I think Kaleb is probably correct on the preprocessing side (which is anything but ideal) - you might be able to use a regex for any of the incoming regex'es to do a replace.... although that has quite the code smell about it.

**Edit:**
An additional thought that just came to me.  If the regex does not need to be in the xsd - i.e. it is there simply because that was "easiest" in the past - you could do the regex validation outside of the xsd.  But, if other systems use the xsd, that is likely not the correct solution, and you can forget I said anything.