# Validation using JAXB and Stax to marshal XML document

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, stax

I have created an XML schema (foo.xsd) and used `xjc` to create my binding classes for JAXB.  Let's say the root element is `collection` and I am writing N `document` objects, which are complex types.

Because I plan to write out large XML files, I am using Stax to write out the `collection` root element, and JAXB to marshal document subtrees using `Marshaller.marshal(JAXBElement, XMLEventWriter)`.  This is the approach recommended by [jaxb's unofficial user's guide](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Different_ways_of_marshalling.html#Marshalling_into_a_subtree).

My question is, how can I validate the XML while it's being marshalled?  If I bind a schema to the JAXB marshaller (using `Marshaller.setSchema()`), I get validation errors because I am only marshalling a subtree (it's complaining that it's not seeing the `collection` root element").  I suppose what I really want to do is bind a schema to the `Stax XMLEventWriter` or something like that.

Any comments on this overall approach would be helpful.  Basically I want to be able to use `JAXB` to marshal and unmarshal large XML documents without running out of memory, so if there's a better way to do this let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some Stax implementations seem to be able to validate output. See the following answer to a similar question:

[Using Stax2 with Woodstox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-xml-file-against-an-xsd-file/690450#690450)

Answer (score 1):

You can make your root collection lazy and instantiate items only when the Marshaller calls `Iterator.next()`. Then a single call to `marshal()` will produce a huge validated XML. You won't run out of memory, because the beans that are already serialized get collected by GC.

Also, it's OK to return `null` as a collection element if it needs to be conditionally skipped. There won't be NPE.

The XML schema validator itself seems to consume little memory even on huge XMLs.

See JAXB's [ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody()](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/blob/ae80415110ec0711d8854f7aa8e59872e580515c/jaxb-ri/runtime/impl/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jaxb/runtime/v2/runtime/property/ArrayElementProperty.java#L92)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.SchemaOutputResolver;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "TestHuge")
public class TestHuge {

    static final boolean MISPLACE_HEADER = true;

    private static final int LIST_SIZE = 20000;

    static final String HEADER = "Header";

    static final String DATA = "Data";

    @XmlElement(name = HEADER)
    String header;

    @XmlElement(name = DATA)
    List<String> data;

    @XmlAnyElement
    List<Object> content;

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestHuge.class);

        final Schema schema = genSchema(jaxbContext);

        final Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setSchema(schema);

        final TestHuge instance = new TestHuge();

        instance.content = new AbstractList<Object>() {

            @Override
            public Object get(final int index) {
                return instance.createChild(index);
            }

            @Override
            public int size() {
                return LIST_SIZE;
            }
        };

        // throws MarshalException ... Invalid content was found starting with element 'Header'
        marshaller.marshal(instance, new Writer() {

            @Override
            public void write(final char[] cbuf, final int off, final int len) throws IOException {}

            @Override
            public void write(final int c) throws IOException {}

            @Override
            public void flush() throws IOException {}

            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException {}
        });

    }

    private JAXBElement<String> createChild(final int index) {
        if (index % 1000 == 0) {
            System.out.println("serialized so far: " + index);
        }
        final String tag = index == getHeaderIndex(content) ? HEADER : DATA;

        final String bigStr = new String(new char[1000000]);
        return new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(tag), String.class, bigStr);
    }

    private static int getHeaderIndex(final List<?> list) {
        return MISPLACE_HEADER ? list.size() - 1 : 0;
    }

    private static Schema genSchema(final JAXBContext jc) throws Exception {
        final List<StringWriter> outs = new ArrayList<>();
        jc.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver() {

            @Override
            public Result createOutput(final String namespaceUri, final String suggestedFileName)
                                                                                                  throws IOException {
                final StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
                outs.add(out);
                final StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);
                streamResult.setSystemId("");
                return streamResult;
            }
        });
        final StreamSource[] sources = new StreamSource[outs.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < outs.size(); i++) {
            final StringWriter out = outs.get(i);
            sources[i] = new StreamSource(new StringReader(out.toString()));
        }
        final SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        final Schema schema = sf.newSchema(sources);
        return schema;
    }
}
```