# Validate XML against two XSDs for Google Images sitemap

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I have an XML file (a sitemap using Google's `<image:image>` extensions) that I need to validate against the two local XSD files, but validation fails because `<url>` doesn't allow `<image:image>` as a child. The full error message is

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: 
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'image:image'.
One of '{"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9":lastmod, 
         "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9":changefreq, 
         "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9":priority}' 
is expected.
```

Here's the sitemap XML I'm trying to validate:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/index.html</loc>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://example.com/images/mysite.jpg</image:loc>
      <image:title>My Site's Logo</image:title>
      <image:caption>Logo for My Site by Andy Warhol (not really)</image:caption>
    </image:image>
  </url>
  ...
</urlset>
```

I'm using the standard XSDs for [sitemaps](http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd) and [Google Images](http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1/sitemap-image.xsd), but since neither references the other I don't see how to make `<image:image>` a valid child of `<url>`.

If it helps, here is the code that performs the validation.

```
Source document = ...
StreamSource[] source = new StreamSource[] {
        new StreamSource(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("sitemap.xsd"), "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"),
        new StreamSource(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("sitemap-image.xsd"), "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1")
    };
SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI).newSchema(source)
             .newValidator().validate(document);
```

The [closest SO question I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624763/xml-to-be-validated-against-multiple-xsd-schemas) requires pre-parsing and splitting up the XML file because the schema to apply varies based on data values. My requirement is much simpler and I would hope much easier to solve.

**Update:** I had the old schema that didn't allow any other children for the  element. sitemaps.org has updated their XSD to add

```
<xsd:any namespace="##other" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="strict"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the sitemap schema allows any element at that location as long as it is from another name space and provided there is a schema around (since the "processContent" is strict. However, your <image> data is not valid, <caption> must appear before <title>.

When I test it on Java 1.6, it validates OK.

Comment: Wow, sitemaps.org must have changed the schema without changing the revision number--probably because the sitemap structure didn't change. I checked the file I linked against what I've had in my application for over a year and of course they differ. The old one doesn't allow any other elements. "Upgrading" to the latest schema fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Your'e welcome. The change is at least backwards compatible. Anyhow, schemas are evil--or, rather, (most of) the use of schemas are;-)

Answer (score 2):

Took me a while to figure out the syntax to do schema validation (Google's own samples don't actually validate against the XSD files):

```
<urlset  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation=
        "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd
        http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1 http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1/sitemap-image.xsd"
         xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
         xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
```