# XML Validation - Using multiple xsd's

Tags: java, xml, validation

I have two xsd files to validate a xml. But the problem is my code takes only one xsd. How to use other xsd in the following code? I dont have idea about where should i place/call 2nd xsd file.

```
             private void validate(File xmlF,File xsd1,File xsd2) {
                    try {
                        url = new URL(xsd.toURI().toString());//  xsd1
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    source = new StreamSource(xml); // xml
                    try {
                        System.out.println(url);
                        schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(url);
                    } catch (SAXException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    validator = schema.newValidator();
                    System.out.println(xml);
                    try {
                        validator.validate(source);
                    } catch (SAXException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Did you already try [`newSchema(Source[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html#newSchema(javax.xml.transform.Source[]))?

Comment: Yes. I tried that way. Its not working , probably because Source[] is used for xml's. We cannot typecast xsd to source.

Comment: As with the previous question regarding this XML validation project, I'd like to point you to [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Your code snippet is far from complete as you define variables outside of this method etc. Putting attention to the way you ask your question, helps us helping you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML to be validated against multiple xsd schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624763/xml-to-be-validated-against-multiple-xsd-schemas)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Plenty of hits when searching on SO or Google. One of them is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624763/xml-to-be-validated-against-multiple-xsd-schemas/2731447#2731447) question, where the author found his own solution and reports the following code to add multiple xsd's to the validator:

```
Schema schema = factory().newSchema(new Source[] {
  new StreamSource(stream("foo.xsd")),
  new StreamSource(stream("Alpha.xsd")),
  new StreamSource(stream("Mercury.xsd")),
});
```

However, when working directly with `InputStream` on `StreamSource`, the resolver is not able to load any referenced XSD files. If, for instance, the file `xsd1` imports or includes a third file (which is not `xsd2`), schema creation will fail. You should either set the system identifier (`setSystemId`) or (even better) use the `StreamSource(File f)` constructor.

Adjusted to your example code:

```
try {
  schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
  schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new Source[] {
    new StreamSource(xsd1), new StreamSource(xsd2)
  });
} catch (SAXException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note:

If working with classpath resources, I'd prefer the `StreamSource(String systemId)` constructor (rather than creating a `File`):

```
new StreamSource(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("a.xsd").toExternalForm());
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as my question above.

Comment: It is the same solution you offered in your comment. That's why I upvoted your comment. OP had trouble implementing it though; I had the code ready in my Eclipse from answering his previous question and simply adjusted it to show how to use Source[]. No hard feelings, I hope?

Comment: @Michael-O that's why you should post it as answer, not comment

Comment: `new StreamSource(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("a.xsd").toExternalForm())` solved my problem, thx!