# Validation failing for images-sitemap using Java code

Tags: java, validation, xsd, xml-sitemap

I have an images sitemap xml file and I am trying to validate it against a schema using Java code:

```
URL schemaFile = new URL("https://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1/sitemap-image.xsd");

Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(new File("web.xml"));
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);

Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(xmlFile);
```

and the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
<url>
    <loc>https://company.com/abc/is/images/A/AA/AAA/AAAA/A/product-name</loc>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>https://company.com/abc/is/image//images/A/AA/AAA/AAAA</image:loc>
    </image:image>
</url>
```

---

The Java validation error I receive is:

```
line: 2
column: 123
message: Cannot find the declaration of element 'urlset'.
```

Comment: Turns out, the answer is here = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009285/xml-validation-using-multiple-xsds/7009977

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the XML, the `urlset` element has no prefix, so it's considered to be in the default namespace: `http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9`. However, in the Java code, you are using the wrong schema (different version/namespace): `https://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1/sitemap-image.xsd`.

So either change the namespace of `urlset` XML element (with prefix `image` maybe?) or load the other schema (v0.9) in your java code.