# xml validation against xsd by using spring java

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd

/*i am facing problem because i have three referenced xsd and i to validate a xml which is comming as jdom element. exception i am getting is "cannot find the declearation ". code is given below: 
Input parameter is : Element param*/

```
     DOMOutputter outputter = new DOMOutputter();
    org.jdom2.Document document=new org.jdom2.Document();
    document.addContent(param.clone());
org.w3c.dom.Document doc=outputter.output(document);

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(doc);
    Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(outputStream);
    TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(xmlSource, outputTarget);
    InputStream xml = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray()); 

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();   
    DocumentBuilder builder;   
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    // create a grammar object.
    Source[] source = {
            new StreamSource(new File("H:/ref2.xsd")),
            new StreamSource(new File("H:/ref1.xsd")),
            new StreamSource(new File("H:/ref.xsd"))};
    Schema schemaGrammar = schemaFactory.newSchema(source);
    validator.validate(new StreamSource(xml));
```

//please suggest

Comment: Please refer this already answered [question][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624763/xml-to-be-validated-against-multiple-xsd-schemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
URL xsdUrlA = this.getClass().getResource("a.xsd");
URL xsdUrlB = this.getClass().getResource("b.xsd");
URL xsdUrlC = this.getClass().getResource("c.xsd");

SchemaFactory schemaFactory = schemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
//---
String W3C_XSD_TOP_ELEMENT =
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n"
   + "<xs:schema xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" elementFormDefault=\"qualified\">\n"
   + "<xs:include schemaLocation=\"" +xsdUrlA.getPath() +"\"/>\n"
   + "<xs:include schemaLocation=\"" +xsdUrlB.getPath() +"\"/>\n"
   + "<xs:include schemaLocation=\"" +xsdUrlC.getPath() +"\"/>\n"
   +"</xs:schema>";
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new StringReader(W3C_XSD_TOP_ELEMENT), "xsdTop"));
```