# Validating XML against XSD

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I need to validate an XML file with a given XSD file. I simply need the method to return true if the validation went fine or false otherwise.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Returns simply true or false (also you don't need any external library):

```
static boolean validateAgainstXSD(InputStream xml, InputStream xsd)
{
    try
    {
        SchemaFactory factory = 
            SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsd));
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(xml));
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't execptions **just** be used for execptional situations and **not** for control flow? I wouldn't consider it execptional, if execute a 'test'. It can pass, or fail. Two options one has to consider. Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-xml-file-against-an-xsd-file

Comment: This code doesn't work when the file to validate contains a DOCTYPE declaration, if someone know why ?

Comment: In case someone gets error "No SchemaFactory tha implements [...]", it's maybe because you did the same error as me, which was using the constant XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI. Replace it with the constant mentioned above.

Comment: In the line

Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsd));

when sending the xsd to validate, it very slow to load the xsd schema, anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 5):

[XMLUnit](https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit) has some nice classes to do this, there is an example in their README file:

```
Validator v = Validator.forLanguage(Languages.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
v.setSchemaSources(Input.fromFile("local.xsd").build());
ValidationResult result = v.validateInstance(new StreamSource(new File("local.xml")));
return result.isValid();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public boolean validate() {
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

  factory.setValidating(true);

  factory.setAttribute(
        "http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage",
        "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
  factory.setAttribute(
        "http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource",
        "http://domain.com/mynamespace/mySchema.xsd");
  Document doc = null;
  try {
    DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    doc = parser.parse("data.xml");
    return true;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This might depends on the library you use but googling around with "how to validate xml file in java" gave me these results where you might find your answer:

[first interesting result](http://www.edankert.com/validate.html)

[second interesting result](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-javaxmlvalidapi/index.html)