# Hows does XML validation with an XSD Work?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validating XML against XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815579/validating-xml-against-xsd)

I am using this code to validate my XML with an XSD

```
        DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // Parse the file. If errors found, they will be printed.
        parser.parse(args[1]);
```

But i want to know how does it work , will it check tag or all data ? 
How reliable it is ?

Comment: To answer your question you should provide the full path of class you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following where after the document is parser the resulting DOM is validated against the XML schema.  You can set an instance of `ErrorHandler` so that you can choose what to do with an validation errors.

```java
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = parser.parse(args[1]);
        DOMSouce source = new DOMSource(document);

        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("customer.xsd"));

        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler());
        validator.validate(source);
    }

}
```

Alternatively you could call `setSchema` on the `DocumentBuilderFactory` so that validation will happen during the parse, but this isn't supported by all DOM parsers:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setSchema%28javax.xml.validation.Schema%29

**For More Information**

Below is a link to an example from my blog where this schema validation approach is used.  In that example a `JAXBSource` instead of a `DOMSource` is used, but everything else is the same.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/validate-jaxb-object-model-with-xml.html