# Validate REST payloads against their associated XML schema definition (XSD)

Tags: xml, web-services, rest, xsd, xml-validation

How can I validate the REST payloads (xml)  against a schema definition?

What should the XSD define at minimum?

would it be a good practice to provide xsds for my rest payloads in XML so the consumers can validate against these xsds before making a call?

Comment: What platform?  What language(s)?

Comment: language is java. <br> i did not understand the platform question.

Comment: What Java platform, if any applies.  I'm not very familiar with Java, so I can't really help there sorry.

Answer (score 0):

So you might get more answers ont his if you tag it with Java, but based on this post ([Validating XML against XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815579/validating-xml-against-xsd) ( you want something like this:

```
static boolean validateAgainstXSD(InputStream xml, InputStream xsd)
{
  try
  {
    SchemaFactory factory = 
        SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsd));
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.validate(new StreamSource(xml));
    return true;
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Your XSD should define all elements, attributes, and records in the XML document, as well as how often they can occur and whether they're nillable at a minimum.  I don't know of a well defined way to provide a WSDL using REST, but you might consider having some API call through your interface that basically provides the WSDL/XSD you're using for consumers.

With that said, why don't you just use a SOAP based interface for this?  REST is great and has its place, but it sounds like you're looking for a messaging protocol with strong types and contracts - which is what SOAP is more designed for.