# Is it possible to validate XML against schemas present in that XML file using Java?

Tags: java, xml

So I have an XML that already has all the schemas specified in the root tag like this

```
<Waybill xmlns="urn:some:uri1"
     xmlns:cac="urn:some:uri2"
     xmlns:cbc="urn:some:uri3"
     xmlns:ext="urn:some:uri4" xmlns:xxx="http://some.url.com">
```

Is it possible to validate my XML against these in the Java code in such a way that I don't have to repeat them in the Java code again?
All the examples I found so far require you to specify the url explicitly in the code

Comment: My XML is a little rusty, but those are just namespaces. The URIs don't really mean much more than a unique string, and they're definitely not schemas. [Here's an XML schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition#XML_DTD_schema_example).

Comment: cac or cbc in this case is a namespace but URIs point to schemas, don't they? At least when I open the file that the URI points to, it contains another XML file that starts with <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ...

Comment: plus Intellij Idea actually validates the XML against those schemas listed in the top and underlines whatever funny change I make in my XML

Comment: Intellij is 80% magic.

Comment: Try this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setValidating(boolean)   

Might need to use the setNamespaceAware property as well.


DocumentBuilderFactory dbf= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setValidating(true)

DocumentBuilder builder=factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc=builder.parse(new File(filename));

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Validating XML against XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815579/validating-xml-against-xsd)

The magic seems to be in this: `XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI`.