# Relative path for JMeter XML Schema?

Tags: xsd, jmeter

I'm using JMeter 2.6, and have the following setup for my test:

```
-
|-test.jmx
|-myschema.xsd
```

I've set up an XML Schema Assertion, and typed `"myschema.xsd"` in the File Name field. Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
HTTP Request
Output schema : error: line=1 col=114 schema_reference.4:
Failed to read schema document 'myschema.xsd', because 
1) could not find the document; 
2) the document could not be read; 
3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

I've tried adding several things to the `path`, including `${__P(user.dir)}` (points to the `home dir` of the user) and `${__BeanShell(pwd())}` (doesn't return anything). I got it working by giving the absolute path, but the script is supposed to be used by others, so that's no good.

I could make it use a property value defined in the command line, but I'd like to avoid it as well, for the same reason.

**How can I correctly point the Assertion to the schema under these circumstances?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary:** in the end I've used *http://path.to.schema/myschema.xsd* as the File Name parameter in the Assertion.

**Explanation:** following Alies Belik's advice, I've found that the code for setting up the schema looks something like this:

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory parserFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
...
parserFactory.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource", xsdFileName);
```

where xsdFileName is a string (the attribute string is actually a constant, I inlined it for readability).

According to e.g. [this page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipvalschm/), the attribute, when in the form a String, is interpreted as an URI - which includes HTTP URLs. Since I already have the schema accessible through HTTP, I've opted for this solution.

Comment: So, apparently the "correct" sequence in SO is: accept own answer, THEN upvote another. Sigh...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have to in this situation

- validate your xml against xsd manually: simply use corresponding java code from e.g. [BeanShell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) or [BeanShell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor);
  here is a pretty nice solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16054/993246 (as well you can use any other you want for this);
- dig into jmeter's sources, amend XML Schema file obtaining to support variables in path (File Name field) - like [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) does;
  but the previous way seems to be much easier;
- run your jmeter test-scenario from shell-script or [ant-task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/pages/projects/jmeter-ant-task.php) which will first copy your xsd to jmeter's /bin dir before script execution - at least XML Schema Assertion can be used "as is".

Perhaps if you will find any other/better - please share it.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I did find another solution by taking your advice and looking into the sources. Whether it's better - that depends on your requirements :). I'll post in a moment, and thanks for the inspiration!

Answer (score 1):

Add the 'myschema.xsd' to the \bin directory of your apache-jmeter next to the 'ApacheJMeter.jar' **or** set the 'File Name' from the 'XML Schema Assertion' to your 'myschema.xsd' from this starting point.

**E.g.**

```
JMeter: C:\Users\username\programs\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\ApacheJMeter.jar

Schema: C:\Users\username\workspace\yourTest\schema\myschema.xsd

File Name: ..\\..\\..\workspace\yourTest\schema\myschema.xsd
```