# Validating xml whose attribute values have quotes in them with xsd in jmeter

Tags: xml, xsd, jmeter

I have an xml whose attributes have quotes in the values. Is there any possible way to validate the xml with the xsd ?

The XML:

```
<root>
    <item size="11"x17""/>
</root>
```

The error:

```
Error displayed: Assertion failure message: fatal: line=5 col=268 Element type "item" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are using jmeter's [XML Schema Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XML_Schema_Assertion).

As well you can try to validate your xml against xsd manually instead: simply use corresponding java code with e.g. [BeanShell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) or [BeanShell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor); here is a pretty nice working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16054/993246 (as well you can use any other you want for this).