# Validating xml w.r.t XSD in java

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I am trying to validate an xml file which is generated w.r.t a schema in xsd format.
The doubt is if I need to pass the url of the schema or the location of schema on my system ?
Similarly, do we need to pass the content of xml file or its location ?

Below is the code snippet I am using -

```
public void validateDTFAgainstXSD()
{
    String inputxml = "C:/Users/file.xml";
    String schemaLocation = "https://github.abcd/schema.xsd";
    try
    {
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        File schemaFile = new File(schemaLocation);
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
        javax.xml.validation.Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

        Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(inputxml));
        validator.validate(source);
        System.out.println("File validated");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("File not validated");
    }       
}
```

Comment: I did a lot of research for my above question.
And among the many questions related to it on the site, this one answers it the BEST - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16054/1472493

Answer (score 1):

There are newSchema() overloads that take either a File object or a Source object. You're passing a File, which is fine.

The Validator.validate() method requires a Source. If you have a filename, you can construct a Source using new StreamSource(new File(filename)). The way you are doing it is wrong: it assumes that the string your are wrapping in the StringReader contains the XML to be validated, not the name of a file containing the XML.

Comment: Getting this error - 
org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.bind.Validator


For this line :    Validator validator = (Validator) schema.newValidator();

Comment: That's just a simple case of importing the Validator class from the wrong package. Basic Java error.