# Mirth Connect and HL7 v3 message validation

Tags: javascript, xml, mirth, hl7-v3

I'm using Mirth Connect (stable version) to create interfaces for HL7v3. I've created an interface to recieve a PRPA_IN201305UV02 message.

At this point I want to do some sort of validation of the incoming XML message. After some search I discovered that HL7 has schemas files (xsd) to verify the correctness of the messages.

So, I'm trying to implement the validation against a xsd file. Searching the mirth forum one of the administrators posted a [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/package-summary.html) to a java library for xml validation.

In my channel source transformer I wrote the javascript based on that link.

```
// parse an XML document into a DOM tree
var parser = Packages.javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
var document = parser.parse(msg);
```

The last line of code is getting me an error when I recieve a message

```
Wrapped java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol
```

I tried also with

```
var document = parser.parse(messageObject.getRawData());
```

But I get the same error.

What is missing here?
Is this the best way to do a XML validation on Mirth Connect?

Thank you

Comment: As an off-topic, "_Unofficial Mirth Connect v3.0 Developer's Guide_" (available at mirthconnect.isarp.com) describes both XML schema and schematron validations. In addition to that you may go with "_Unofficial Developer's Guide to HL7v3 Basics_" (hl7.isarp.com) to see what level of validation you may achieve by these tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-xml-file-against-an-xsd-file) answer

And I transformed that to Javascript in Mirth

```
var schemaFile = new Packages.java.io.File("C:\\schema.xsd");
var url = new Packages.java.net.URL("file:C:\\input.xml");
var xmlFile = new Packages.javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(url);
var schemaFactory = Packages.javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
var schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);

var validator = schema.newValidator();

try {
    validator.validate(xmlFile);
    logger.info('valid');
} catch (err) {
    logger.error(err.toString());
}
```

You need to download JAXP (Java API for XML Processing) from [here](http://jaxp.java.net/)

I hope it helps others