# XML Validation error on attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I am confused as to why my XML schema will not pass Java's xml schema validation. I got my java validation code from [link to the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-xml-file-against-an-xsd-file). It should be standard stuff. I am told that a problem was found starting at: attribute. It is at lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 48.

My xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

 <xs:element name ="Entries">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="entry">
        <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines 8 and 9 are both missing a closing quote on the `type` attribute. This fixed XML passes validation for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

 <xs:element name ="Entries">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="entry">
        <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

### EDIT 1

Ok, upon further examination it turns out the xml is just malformed. The `<xs:attribute>` tag can not be a child of the `<xs:element>` tag. If you're trying to define two attributes on the "entry" element, your schema definition needs to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="Entries">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="entry">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have copied and pasted my code, the missing " on lines 8 and 9 were just typos. I still have the error.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing "

Lines 8 and 9 should be

```
<xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have copied and pasted my code, the missing " on lines 8 and 9 were just typos. I still have the error.