# How to improve speed large xml validation against xsd in Java?

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I'm trying to validate a very XML (~200MB) against XSD. It's taking almost 3 hours. I'm not sure what am I doing wrong here?

```
    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File(this.productExtraInfoXsd));

    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new File(filePath));

    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
    DOMResult result = new DOMResult();

    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.validate(domSource, result);
```

Comment: You might not be doing anything wrong. Run a profiler on your job and see if it's getting stuck in a particular place. If not, most likely it's just taking that long to process it.

Comment: Is there anyway I can speed up the process?

Comment: Run a profiler. Look for hotspots. If there aren't any, get a faster computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this article  on XML unmarshalling from Marco Tedone see [here](http://tedone.typepad.com/blog/2011/06/unmarshalling-benchmark-in-java-jaxb-vs-stax-vs-woodstox.html). Based on his  you can see Stax

```
XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(fileInputStream);
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(new StAXSource(xmlStreamReader));
```

Comment: According to what is written in the article, using StAX is slower than  using "Pure JAXB unmarshalling" version, just using StAX will save memory. So I think that if @toy wants to speed up the validation process, this is not a good solution ... or am I missing something?

Comment: @Paolo - I don't believe constantlearner meant `unmarshalling` in the JAXB sense.  This is simply suggesting using a `StAXSource` instead of a `DOMSource`.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan If so than ok, I have actually just found an old stackoverflow topic that is reporting right what you are saying ...

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this [stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-xml-file-against-an-xsd-file).
Here is written that:

> You should not use the DOMParser to validate a document (unless your
>   goal is to create a document object model anyway). This will start
>   creating DOM objects as it parses the document - wasteful if you
>   aren't going to use them.

Maybe it will be useful!

Comment: +1. 3 hours does seem excessive for a 200Mb validation, though it depends a bit what's in the schema (e.g. expensive regular expressions). But the first step is to see how long it takes if you don't build a DOM at the same time.