# Java. XML. how to validate certain part of xml document against XSD Schema?

Tags: java, xml, validation, xpath, xsd

I have a SOAP response from a web-service in String and `Document` formats, and I have a method that validates it. The problem is that I have to validate Node `<Result>`.

I have already got this node, but do not know how to get child nodes with tags and etc.

```
Node result = (Node)xPath.compile("//Result").evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);

        <Result>
        <playerID>some id</playerID>
        <partnerUID>some partner uid</partnerUID>
        <registrationLevel>some registration level</registrationLevel>
        <properties>
           <property>
              <key>some key</key>
              <value>some value</value>
           </property>
           <property>...</property>
        </Result>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: What child nodes do you want to get? How does your `<Result/>` element look like? What do you _actually_ and in detail want to do?

Comment: @dirkk I have update my question, I have an XSD schema for this part, and I need to validate it...is there any way to get child nodes as a String, including tags?

Comment: If you have an XSD schema, why don't you validate it by a Validator? Looks to me like you want to do it by hand, which is error-prone and as well overly complicated. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-xml-file-against-an-xsd-file to learn how to validate your XML against a schema

Comment: @dirkk the problem is, that I can't generate proper XSD schema for this XML file, which is a SOAP response from a webservice. I don't know how to deal with "Soap:envelope" tags

Comment: You certainly can also validate only parts of your XML against an XSD. However, as both your statements are contradicting each other I am now unsure if you have an XSD file or not. If you have, even if only for the portion of XML you actually want to check, use XSD validation rather than manually checking everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I validate XML file against XSD using this way.I think this will help you.

```
public String validateXMLSchema() throws SAXException, IOException
{
    File folder = new File("xsdPath");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    String tempXsdFile;

    for( int i=0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++ )
    {
        if(listOfFiles[i].isFile())
        {
            tempXsdFile = listOfFiles[i].getName();

            try
            {
                SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

                Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(xsdPath + tempXsdFile));

                Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
                validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File("C://Users//test.xml")));
                return tempXsdFile;
            }
            catch (IOException | SAXException e)
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR: XML not well known"+ e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I have almost the same method, the problem is that I can't make a proper XSD schema for my xml file and I decided to validate only the part I need

Comment: SOLVED! This is the greatest [tool](https://code.google.com/p/jing-trang/downloads/list) I found so far - generates great XSD schema.