# How to validate individual xml fields against xml schema in java

Tags: java, xml, validation

I'm wondering if there is a way to validate xml field by field in java.
I have an app that allow to read xml file, change data and save new xml file.
I have to validate changed data, and show which field is wrong. I know i can validate the whole file, but i need to know which specific field is wrong.

Do you know the way to do this? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-xml-file-against-an-xsd-file

Comment: I know how to validate xml file, but it doesn't say which field is filled wrong...

Comment: yes, but validation exception contains the reason or not?

Comment: yes, but the user won't understand what the error say. I want to automatically point the wrong field.

Comment: you will have to handle the error and create a readable error message by your own.