# Validate only XSD (XML schema) in Java

Tags: java, xsd, xsd-validation

I would like to validate XSD (XML schema) against the W3C XSD specification in Java.
I appreciate any example.

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Bests,
Rómeó Nagy

Comment: google jaxb schema validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new schema instance with SchemaFactory it throws an SAXException if the input schema document was invalid. Suppose your xsd is present in file:

```
    File schemaFile = new File("pathToXsd");
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    try {
      Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
      System.out.println("Schema was invalid");
    }
    System.out.println("Schema was valid.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XSD file that you want to validate is just an XML document that has an associated [XSD file](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema) that defines what constitutes a valid XML document.

For details on various ways to parse an XML document with validation, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-xml-file-against-an-xsd-file).

The XML file is your XSD file. The schema file you use to validate your XML file is http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.