# How to parse a XML file to see if it's valid before writing to it

Tags: java, xml, parsing

Following this [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/) I was able to create an XML file and following this [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/?utm_source=mkyong&utm_medium=author&utm_campaign=related-post&utm_content=8) I was able to parse the XML file

I now want know how to check if the xml is a valid format before adding another Staff, if the xml is malformed it will exit out and give an error that it can't parse.

If it parses a gibberish file such as this, it will exit and not continue

```
asdsadasfsadf
```

If it parses a valid XML but not in the correct format, it will exit also (the first node is root instead of company)

```
<root>
<staff id="1001">
    <firstname>yong</firstname>
    <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
    <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
    <salary>100000</salary>
</staff>
<staff id="2001">
    <firstname>low</firstname>
    <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
    <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
    <salary>200000</salary>
</staff>
</root>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: define a XSD, let JABX (or any other XML framework) generate mapper classes and configure the *unmarshaller* to check validity of the document on load.

Comment: Read about : [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/)

Comment: @Thenikedestroyer check out his question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-xml-file-against-an-xsd-file#16054

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are two things you are trying to achieve: check to see if your xml is well formed, and check to see if it is valid (valid xml conforms to a DTD or XSD).

To check to see if is well formed, you can just simply try and parse it with any major xml parser, it will throw an exception of it is not well formed.

To check to see if it is valid, validate it against a schema (I would recommend using an XSD and not DTD but that is just me) there are many ways to do this, a few are mentioned here [What's the best way to validate an XML file against an XSD file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-xml-file-against-an-xsd-file#16054)

Additionally if you validate your xml against a schema you will also be checking that it is well formed, because only well formed xml can be validated.