# How to validate XML at tag and attribute level

Tags: java, xml

I understand XML validation.. but the validator API e.g. one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732/whats-the-best-way-to-validate-an-xml-file-against-an-xsd-file) simply returns a true/false. I need something like ... x tag is now allowed, y attribute is not allowed, z tag is not allowed. Kind of field level validation which provides a list of errors, rather than a true/false. Any way to do it?

I believe use case is strong.. since programmer/tester would need to know what exactly is wrong in XML rather than just a true/false. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set an [ErrorHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.html) on a [Validator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Validator.html)

Comment: no ways sir.. it stops at first error! If there are two errors, I want both of them to be logged!